# Step by step procedure for creating a Maven build file

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, struts

I have developed a project using Struts 2.2.3, Spring 3.0, Hibernate 3 and Apache Tomcat in Eclipse. Now I need to create a Maven build file. How?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this is related to Spring, Hibernate or Struts (other than you using those dependencies). You may want to consider removing those tags.

As for Maven, ask Google for a decent Maven tutorial if you need step-by-step instructions. Essentially, however, you need to make yourself familiar with the [POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).

Comment: My requirement is spring,hibernate,struts. so developed project in that way.give me a simple pom.xml file for run the application. my project structure is the following way.action files contain src/com/action package and dao classes are in src/com/dao package like this.

Answer (score 1):

1. if u don't have maven plugin installed in ur eclipse then install it
2. import ur project as maven project in eclipse, now u will see a pom.xml in ur project structure
3. add dependency for  Spring, Hibernate and Struts in pom.xml(u can get all dependency from here https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#welcome).

Answer (score 0):

1) Install maven plugins from eclipse - M2E - http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/
[image]

2) Right Click and Select your project in the eclipse "Project Explorer" View.

3) Click on "Convert" -> "Convert To Maven Project"
[image]

4) The above steps give a quick and dirty approach.

5) You would need to understand dependencies, repositories, dependency scoping to use maven in optimal way to manage a project. Add Build/Plugin/Dependency section to manage third party jars and also update jar/war pom artifact type for your project.